# Control flow throughput

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a flow that receives a message (a list) with 400 records. For each record it creates a message and save it to a MQ Queue (Q-Records-IN).

There's another flow that's watching the queue (Q-Records-IN) and for each message, process it.
On this case, the first flow is very fast so it creates the 400 message quickly.

I need to control the throughput of the second flow, limiting it to process in the maximum 10 messages simultaneously.

How can I do this?
I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a space issue where you can not queue 400 records in MQ on the queue, or are those just example numbers and the real numbers are larger where it is a concern?  As to ways to do this, you would either need to be able to inquire the queue depth or get some form of confirmation back from the APP or using by using MQ reporting options to get COD responses.  I'm not entirely sure how from a IIB message flow you would be able to tie it together.  Possibly you could just put a pause in the flow that would approximate how long it takes the app to process 10 messages.

Comment: @JoshMc 400 is just an example, can be thousands of messages. A pause isn't an option because there's no way to calculate an average time for this transaction. I'm looking for a real throughput control solution using IIB options. Thanks